# Populate a certain number of row between 2 date

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle12c

I'm looking for a way to populate certain number of rows between 2 dates so that I could perform standard deviation. The populated data will have default value of 0.

Here is sample of my table:

```
+------------+---------+-------+
|    Date    | Account | Value |
+------------+---------+-------+
| 01/01/2020 |       1 |   100 |
| 07/01/2020 |       1 |   200 |
+------------+---------+-------+
```

What I want it to become like this:

```
+------------+---------+-------+
|    Date    | Account | Value |
+------------+---------+-------+
| 01/01/2020 |       1 |   100 |
| 02/01/2020 |       1 |     0 |
| 03/01/2020 |       1 |     0 |
| 04/01/2020 |       1 |     0 |
| 05/01/2020 |       1 |     0 |
| 06/01/2020 |       1 |     0 |
| 07/01/2020 |       1 |   200 |
+------------+---------+-------+
```

Is it possible to construct this statement?

Comment: Your table is guaranteed to have exactly two rows, one wth the start date and one with the end date, when we run the query?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a recursive query:

```sql
WITH cte (mydate, account, gap_months) AS 
(
  -- Generate dates to fill in gaps, per account
  SELECT 
    MIN(mydate) OVER(PARTITION BY account) AS mydate, -- Get min date, per account
    account,
    ABS(
      MONTHS_BETWEEN(
        MIN(mydate) OVER(PARTITION BY account),
        MAX(mydate) OVER(PARTITION BY account)
      )
    ) AS gap_months -- Get number of months between min / max dates, per account
  FROM mytable

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 
    ADD_MONTHS(mydate, 1) AS mydate, -- Get next month's date
    account, 
    gap_months - 1 -- Decrease counter
  FROM cte
  WHERE gap_months > 0 -- Stop recursion
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
  cte.mydate, 
  cte.account, 
  COALESCE(mt.value, 0) AS value
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN mytable mt ON cte.mydate = mt.mydate 
  AND cte.account = mt.account -- Get existing data
ORDER BY cte.mydate
```

[DB Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/77032/29)

Comment: Oops, I may have misread your question.  I assumed the rows you wanted between the min / max dates was one per month (`MM/DD/YYYY` format) based on your expected output -- hence the `MONTHS_BETWEEN` and `ADD_MONTHS` logic.  If it's actually days, then you'd need to modify it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **hierarchical query** as following:

```
SQL> with YOUR_TABLE (date_, account, value)
  2  as
  3  (select date'2020-01-01', 1, 100 from dual
  4  union all select date'2020-01-07', 1, 200 from dual)
  5  ,
  6  -- YOUR QUERY STARTS FROM HERE
  7  -- WITH
  8  MIN_MAX_DATES AS (
  9      SELECT
 10          ACCOUNT,
 11          MIN(DATE_) AS MINDATE,
 12          MAX(DATE_) AS MAXDATE
 13      FROM YOUR_TABLE
 14      GROUP BY ACCOUNT
 15  ), ALL_DATES AS (
 16      SELECT
 17          MINDATE + COLUMN_VALUE - 1 DATE_,
 18          ACCOUNT
 19      FROM MIN_MAX_DATES
 20          CROSS JOIN TABLE ( CAST(MULTISET(
 21              SELECT LEVEL
 22              FROM DUAL
 23              CONNECT BY LEVEL <= MAXDATE - MINDATE + 1
 24          ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST) )
 25  )
 26  SELECT A.DATE_,
 27           A.ACCOUNT,
 28           COALESCE(T.VALUE, 0) AS VALUE FROM ALL_DATES A
 29  LEFT JOIN YOUR_TABLE T ON T.DATE_ = A.DATE_;

DATE_        ACCOUNT      VALUE
--------- ---------- ----------
01-JAN-20          1        100
02-JAN-20          1          0
03-JAN-20          1          0
04-JAN-20          1          0
05-JAN-20          1          0
06-JAN-20          1          0
07-JAN-20          1        200

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one simple way to do this with a recursive cte:

```
with cte(mydate, maxdate) as (
    select min(mydate) mydate, max(mydate) maxdate from mytable
    union all
    select mydate + 1, maxdate from cte where mydate < maxdate
)
select c.mydate, coalesce(t.value, 0) value
from cte c
left join mytable t on t.mydate = c.mydate
order by c.mydate
```

The cte generates a list of dates between the smallest and greatest dates available in the table, and then left joins it with the table.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9bea041a08c0f8462ad6f3d596001bba)**:

```
MYDATE    | VALUE
:-------- | ----:
01-JAN-20 |   100
02-JAN-20 |     0
03-JAN-20 |     0
04-JAN-20 |     0
05-JAN-20 |     0
06-JAN-20 |     0
07-JAN-20 |   200
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this with a procedure:

```
create procedure insert_emptry_date
as

cursor c_cur 
is
select (nvl(date_c - lag(date_c) over (order by date_c), 0)) as a 
       , date_c 
from test
order by date_c;;

var_a number := 0;

begin

for rec in c_cur loop
   if rec.a > 0 then
      var_a := rec.a -1;
   end if;
   dbms_output.put_line(var_a);

   if var_a > 0 then
   loop
      insert into test values ((rec.date_c - var_a), 1, 0);
      commit;
      var_a := var_a -1;
      exit when var_a = 0;
   end loop;
   end if;

end loop;

end;
/
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bc73a296dc5262c4ec74809088f935b4)

In this code I user cursor `c_cur` to get the difference between two dates and the date from which I will insert other dates.

I use variable `var_a` to save the difference I have fetched with the cursor reduced by 1 because I do not want to add the same date. Then I decrese that value untill it is 0. (In your example that value will be: 5 then 4, 3, 2, 1).